# JSON - Parsing quick help (object name)

Tags: json, parsing, object, naming, convention

Parsing some JSON and one [edit: +"of the"] names for an object is "media:content".

Say I just want to quickly console.log this by,

c.l(results.entry[0].media:content.property)

how must I format that object name so it doesn't throw me a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
results.entry[0]["media:content"].property
```